# How to get integer value of datetime in java?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, date-formatting

I'm working in a Java project and I need to get a numeric "value" of a `DateTime` in Java. For example: the datetime is `2020-07-22T17:40:56.235+05:30` and I want to convert it into `20200722174056235`. I am using `DateTime` methods like `getDate()`, `getYear()` to make this kind of value.

Is there any way or any method to covert a datetime into such a numeric value?

```
DateTime calendar = new DateTime();

        int year       = calendar.getYear();
        int month      = calendar.getMonthOfYear();
        int dayOfMonth = calendar.getDayOfMonth();            
        int hour       = calendar.getHourOfDay();// 12 hour clock
        int minute     = calendar.getMinuteOfHour();
        int second     = calendar.getSecondOfMinute();
        int millisecond= calendar.getMillisOfSecond();
       
        String dt = String.valueOf((year)+
                String.valueOf(month)+
                String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)+
                String.valueOf(hourOfDay)+
                String.valueOf(minute)+
                String.valueOf(second)+
                String.valueOf(millisecond));
        return Long.valueOf(dt);
```

I need to use joda `DateTime` only.

Comment: What exact type is `calendar`, the object you're starting with? Is it joda DateTime?

Comment: Can you clarify the question: What is `DateTime()`? Do you mean the `java.time.ZonedDateTime` class? But the code snippet seems to work with legacy `java.util.Calendar` class?

Comment: i have update post

Comment: Do you need to use Joda's `DateTime` or can it be something else? Java has a great new time API ([java.time](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro)) that is inspired by Joda's.

Comment: Why not use getMillis()?  It's a super useful long that means exactly that date and time.

Comment: Yes i need to use joda datetime only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a formatter.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
    
    DateTime calendar = new DateTime();
    String formatted = calendar.toString(formatter);
    Long numericValue = Long.parseLong(formatted);
    
    System.out.println(numericValue);
```

Output when I ran the code in my time zone just now:

> 20200722210458862

**Alternate way:** Only if this is for a library method that I expect to be called often and where efficiency may be a concern, I might consider not formatting and parsing a string. The following gives the same result.

```
    long numericValue = calendar.getYear();
    numericValue = numericValue * 100 + calendar.getMonthOfYear();
    numericValue = numericValue * 100 + calendar.getDayOfMonth();
    numericValue = numericValue * 100 + calendar.getHourOfDay();
    numericValue = numericValue * 100 + calendar.getMinuteOfHour();
    numericValue = numericValue * 100 + calendar.getSecondOfMinute();
    numericValue = numericValue * 1000 + calendar.getMillisOfSecond();
```

**Did your code work?**

Your code probably formatted one-digit values into just one character in the string, so your string would typically be too short and miss some zeroes. For example:

```
Correct:        20200722210458862 (2020 07 22 21 04 58 862)
From your code:   202072221458862 (2020  7 22 21  4 58 862)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code snippet

```
public class ValidateString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pattern = "yyyyMMddHHmmss"; // Change the pattern occording to your need
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.